# How to use midpoint method to integrate a particle

Tags: c++, integration, numerical-methods, physics-engine

I'm using Euler method to numerically integrate particles in a physics engine.

```
float inverseMass;
Vector3 position, velocity;
Vector3 sumForces, gravity, inputForce;
void Particle::Integrate(float dt) {
   sumForces = (gravity+inputForce)*dt;
   Vector3 a = sumForces*inverseMass;
   velocity += a;
   position += velocity*dt;
}
```

I would like to implement a better integrator with Midpoint method. Based on this course https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/pbm/constraints.pdf, with Midpoint method you take a full euler step, then evaluate the force on the particle at the midpoint and then take a step using that midpoint value.

[image]

I implemented the first step.

```
void Particle::Integrate(float dt) {
   //Take full Euler step
   Vector3 sumForces = (gravity+inputForce)*dt;
   Vector3 a = sumForces*inverseMass;
   Vector3 tempVelocity = a+velocity;
   Vector3 deltaX += tempVelocity*dt;

   Vector3 midpoint = deltaX + position;

}
```

How do I continue from here though? How do I calculate the force at midpoint? Do I just calculate it at half time step, but then what is the purpose of calculating the midpoint position?

Comment: You've mashed the calculation of velocity into your `Integrate` function. This makes it harder to work with abstract concepts like the method of integration. It should be easier to see what to do if `Integrate` called another function to get velocities; the `Integrate` function should need no knowledge of things like forces and mass.

Comment: Thanks @JaMiT, I'll try to restructure my code going forward.

Comment: x + delta x / 2 isn't exactly the midpoint, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider that your state contains two main components, position x and velocity v. The method has to be formulated uniformly for the full state,

```
dx1 = v*dt,           dv1 = acc(t,x,v)*dt
dx2 = (v+0.5*dv1)*dt, dv2 = acc(t+0.5*dt, x+0.5*dx1, v+0.5*dv1)*dt

x = x + dx2,          v = v+dv2.
```

Having written down the formulas from first principles, you can now see that it is relatively easy to eliminate the `dx` vectors. Thus it remains to compute

```
dv1 = acc(t,x,v)*dt,
dv2 = acc(t+0.5*dt, x+0.5*v*dt, v+0.5*dv1)*dt,
x = x + (v+0.5*dv1)*dt,
v = v + dv2
```

Comment: Hey thanks very much for the reply, Lutz! Unfortunately I can't quite grasp this. Shouldn't the change in velocity be calculated from the forces that affect the particle `dv = sumForces*inverseMass`? Why are we calculating it based on the previous position x(?) and previous velocity v `dv1 = acc(t,x,v)*dt`?
 Are we not using Newtonian Mechanics?

Comment: You might have time-depending forces, such as a motor. You can have position dependent forces, of which the most common class are gradient fields of potential energies. You can have velocity dependent forces, main examples are air and fluid friction laws. I formulated the acceleration function in this generality to allow all these influences.

Comment: Oh okay thanks! I guess if you don't have time-dependent or velocity-dependent forces, which I don't right now, there's no point in using midpoint or higher level runge-kutta methods.

Comment: Yes, if the force is constant, then `x=x0+v0*t+0.5*F/m*t^2` is the exact solution. A correctly implemented second order method will replicate this, up to floating point noise.

Comment: Sorry I miswrote lol, I meant if you don't have position or velocity-depenent forces. I do have time dependent forces.

Comment: Then the force computation decouple. You could use a leapfrog scheme to reduce the number of acceleration evaluations by half.

Comment: This is a too advanced terminology for me unfortunately, but I am correct to assume that in this particular case Euler integration with step dt/2, would give the same result as midpoint integration with step dt?

Comment: No, Euler in the quadrature case is the left Riemann sum, with order 1, while the midpoint method still remains the midpoint rule, with error order 2.